# Database-first no primary key from database

Tags: entity-framework

I build my `DataContext` with database-first and I have this entity:

```
public partial class Salutation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SalutationShort { get; set; }
    public string SalutationLong { get; set; }
    public string LetterSalutation { get; set; }
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
var s = new Salutation()
        {
            SalutationShort = "Mr.",
            LetterSalutation = "Mister"
        };

context.Salutations.Add(s);
var xx = context.SaveChanges();
```

Problem: I can't force the database to generate a valid Id.

The first try give's '0' as primary key, following calls results in an error because '0' is already in use.

Did i miss something?

By the way, is there any reason why

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

isn't called??

Thanks

Peter

Comment: Check your model. Is Id an EntityKey?

Comment: Hi, you talk about the Database? Yes, Id is the PrimaryKey. If you talk about the POCO, i can't find a way to define Id as EnitiyKey Thanks Peter

Comment: If you look at your edmx, is Id marked as EntityKey? You can check if you right click on it and select properties.

Comment: Hi, i checked it.  Id is marked as EntityKey, with StoreGeneratedPattern = Identity

Comment: Solved,AutiIncrement in SQLServer was not set. Thanks Peter